# Why is there only one infinite cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory

Let G and H be groups with G (which is generated by g) an infinite cyclic group, and let h be an element of H. Prove that there is exactly one homomorphism f which maps from G to H for which f(g)=h. I know that the integers under addition are an infinite cyclic group but why aren't there any others? If we have a homomorphism from G why does it imply that H is the integers under addition?

Comment: First point: $H$ need not be the integers under addition; nowhere in your question did you say that $h$ generates $H$; and even if it did, nowhere did you say that $h$ is of infinite order.

Comment: Second point: And even if $h$ generates $H$ and is of infinite order, it still might not happen that $H$ **is** the integers under addition. Nonetheless in this situation $H$ **is isomorphic to** the integers under addition. For example, the set
$$H = \{2^n \bigm| n \in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
under the operation of multiplication is an infinite cyclic group, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, the isomorphism is given by the function $n \mapsto 2^n$, and $H$ is generated by the infinite order element $2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is generated by $h$, then and you consider the map $f : G\rightarrow H$ given by sending $g$ to $h$.

Then to make it a homomorphism, it must send...

$f(g^2) = f(g)^2 = h^2$

$f(g^3) = f(g)^3 = h^3$

$f(g^{-1}) =f(g)^{-1} = h^{-1}$

...etc, you get the idea.

It's pretty obvious that under the assumption that $g,h$ generate $G,H$ that this is injective and surjective, hence an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

For any group $G$ and element $g\in G$, there exists one and only one homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb Z\to G$ with $f(1)=g$ (namely, $n\mapsto g^n$). If $G$ is cyclic and $G=\langle g\rangle$, this $f$ is onto and we have $G\cong \mathbb Z/\ker f$. If $\ker f\ne 0$, the quotient (and hence $G$) is finite; since we are only interested in infinite $G$, we care only for the case $\ker f=0$. But then $G\cong \mathbb Z/0\cong \mathbb Z$.